# Loading Google Maps JavaScript Places API as page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the Google Maps Places API to have the ability to autocomplete searches for places. Currently, I am loading in the Google Maps JavaScript API with the following code:

```html
window.onload = function () {
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

The issue with the code above, is that I have to wait for the page to be fully loaded, before the Places API is loaded into the page. This results in a few seconds of me being unable to search even though to me, the user, it seems as if the page is fully loaded.

The reason that it is currently placed within the window.onload is because the JavaScript Places API needs an input field to attach to, which needs to be loaded before I try to access it.

My question is, is there any other way of loading in the Google Maps Places JavaScript API to not have a few seconds of the page seeming like it's loaded? Or, is there anything else I can do to have this issue avoided?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove **async** and **defer** from your link to load it synchronously. I am not sure if it is the right thing to do but it will definitely fix your issue.

Comment: I am not using async and defer

Answer (score 0):

You could disable your input field, and/or overlay your page with a busy indicator of some sort early on, then only enable the input field and get rid of the busy indicator in your `onload` function, after you set up autocomplete.

Comment: I've found another solution below. I will use the two together. Thank you 

P.S. I tried upvoting your comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I place the script after the HTML element is loaded, the browser will still show that the page is being loaded as the Google Maps Places API is loaded in.